# how to make opengl mipmaps sharper?

Tags: opengl, gis, mipmaps, blurry

I am rewriting an opengl-based gis/mapping program. Among other things, the program allows you to load raster images of nautical charts, fix them to lon/lat coordinates and zoom and pan around on them.

The previous version of the program uses a custom tiling system, where in essence it manually creates mipmaps of the original image, in the form of 256x256-pixel tiles at various power-of-two zoom levels. A tile for zoom level n - 1 is constructed from four tiles from zoom level n, using a simple average-of-four-points algorithm. So, it turns off opengl mipmapping, and instead when it comes time to draw some part of the chart at some zoom level, it uses the tiles from the nearest-match zoom level (i.e., the tiles are in power-of-two zoom levels but the program allows arbitrary zoom levels) and then scales the tiles to match the actual zoom level. And of course it has to manage a cache of all these tiles at various levels.

It seemed to me that this tiling system was overly complex. It seemed like I should be able to let the graphics hardware do all of this mipmapping work for me. So in the new program, when I read in an image, I chop it into textures of 1024x1024 pixels each. Then I fix each texture to its lon/lat coordinates, and then I let opengl handle the rest as I zoom and pan around.

It works, but the problem is: My results are a bit blurrier than the original program, which matters for this application because you want to be able to read text on the charts as early as possible, zoom-wise. So it's seeming like the simple average-of-four-points algorithm the original program uses gives better results than opengl + my GPU, in terms of sharpness.

I know there are several glTexParameter settings to control some aspects of how mipmaps work. I've tried various combinations of GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL (anywhere from 0 to 10) with various settings for GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER. When I set GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL to 0 (no mipmaps), I certainly get "sharp" results, but they are *too* sharp, in the sense that pixels just get dropped here and there, so the numbers are unreadable at intermediate zooms. When I set GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL to a higher value, the image looks quite good when you are zoomed far out (e.g., when the whole chart fits on the screen), but as you zoom in to intermediate zooms, you notice the blurriness especially when looking at text on the charts. (I.e., if it weren't for the text you might think "wow, opengl is doing a nice job of smoothly scaling my image." but with the text you think "why is this chart out of focus?")

My understanding is that basically you tell opengl to generate mipmaps, and then as you zoom in it picks the appropriate mipmaps to use, and there are some limited options for interpolating between the two closest mipmap levels, and either using the closest pixels or averaging the nearby pixels. However, as I say, none of these combinations seem to give quite as clear results, at the same zoom level on the chart (i.e., a zoom level where text is small but not minuscule, like the equivalent of "7 point" or "8 point" size), as the previous tile-based version.

My conclusion is that the mipmaps that opengl creates are simply blurrier than the ones the previous program created with the average-four-point algorithm, and no amount of choosing the right mipmap or LINEAR vs NEAREST is going to get the sharpness I need.

**Specific questions**:

(1) Does it seem right that opengl is in fact making blurrier mipmaps than the average-four-points algorithm from the original program?

(2) Is there something I might have overlooked in my use of glTexParameter that could give sharper results using the mipmaps opengl is making?

(3) Is there some way I can get opengl to make sharper mipmaps in the first place, such as by using a "cubic" filter or otherwise controlling the mipmap creation process? Or for that matter it seems like I could use the same average-four-points code to manually generate the mipmaps and hand them off to opengl. But I don't know how to do that...

Comment: The mapping from texture coordinates to pixels is a bit tricky. Imagine each pixel being a small square. Texture coordinates 0 and 1 don't hit the bordering pixels in the center but they hit their border. So by a naive, pixel based addressing of the texture's contents you may hit the exact middle between pixels and thus introduce some "blurring".

Comment: See [this](http://www.mindcontrol.org/~hplus/graphics/opengl-pixel-perfect.html). Also, it seems that you are using GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP from your description. Although it's probably the same, using EXT_FRAMEBUFFER_OBJECT's `glGenerateMipmap` might be worth a shot. If shaders are an option, you could do your own mip-filtering with HW acceleration. Lastly, if separating the text labels from the terrain data is a possible option, you could do that too (and for example display the labels with a distance-map based algorithm which gives very very nice antialiased results at all magnifications).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

(1) it seems unlikely; I'd expect it just to use a box filter, which is average four points in effect. Possibly it's just switching from one texture to a higher resolution one at a different moment — e.g. it "Chooses the mipmap that most closely matches the size of the pixel being textured", so a 256x256 map will be used to texture a 383x383 area, whereas the manual system it replaces may always have scaled down from 512x512 until the target size was 256x256 or less.

(2) not that I'm aware of in base GL, but if you were to switch to GLSL and the programmable pipeline then you could use the 'bias' parameter to texture2D if the problem is that the lower resolution map is being used when you don't want it to be. Similarly, the [GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/EXT/texture_lod_bias.txt) extension can do the same in the fixed pipeline. It's an NVidia extension from a decade ago and is something all programmable cards could do, so it's reasonably likely you'll have it.

(EDIT: reading the extension more thoroughly, texture bias migrated into the core spec of OpenGL in version 1.4; clearly my man pages are very out of date. Checking the [1.4 spec](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version1.4/glspec14.pdf), page 279, you can supply a GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS)

(3) yes — if you disable GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP then you can use glTexImage2D to supply whatever image you like for every level of scale, that being what the 'level' parameter dictates. So you can supply completely unrelated mip maps if you want.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Aha! The "level" parameter is the key, so now I understand you can use glTexImage2D to provide your own mipmaps. I will try it and report back if it increases the sharpness. As a follow-up question, is the way it works that if you provide a mipmap for a certain level opengl uses it, and if you don't provide it, it generates one for you (up to the max mipmaps specified)? And does it generate those mipmaps up front, or only as they are actually needed?

Comment: Although if what you say for question (1) is true, it seems like I'm doomed. Although if what you say for question (2) is true, I'm not necessarily doomed, but potentially in for a lot or work... Or actually, perhaps in (3) by providing mipmaps one size too large for the given level I can achieve the same effect???

Comment: @M Katz: OpenGL didn't generate mip maps in early versions, hence the glu method that automatically scales and uploads a texture at every level. So I think the default is for GL to do nothing. GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP generates new mip maps when level 0 is uploaded, its replacement in 3.0 is glGenerateMipmap which generates mip maps only upon command. So either way, you've got to give GL a push to get mip maps generated. Supposing my guess for (1) is correct, you should be able to fix the problem using GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS as per my edit.

Comment: Woo hoo! By using gl.glTexEnvf( gl.GL_TEXTURE_FILTER_CONTROL, gl.GL_TEXTURE_LOD_BIAS, -0.5 ) before gl.glTexImage2D() it stops the blurring effect. I still have to compare my results against the old program at a number of zoom levels, but so far it looks good. Thanks for the great diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific points, the four-point filtering you mention is equivalent to box-filtering. This is less blurry than higher-order filters, but can result in aliasing patterns. One of the best filters is the Lanczos filter. I suggest you calculate all of your mipmap levels from the base texture using a Lanczos filter and crank up the anisotropic filtering settings on your graphics card.

I assume that the original code managed textures itself because it was designed to view data sets that are too large to fit into graphics memory. This was probably a bigger problem in the past, but is still a concern.

Comment: Well, it's actually not a requirement of this program to read in such large images (i.e., where the entire image can't fit into current-generation graphics memory). And in this case the caching code was adding a lot of complexity and mystery to the code base, so there was an immediate pragmatic reason for simplifying the code. But your point is well taken that in general if you want to support arbitrary image sizes you'll need to do some kind of caching on your own.

Comment: Sorry. I must have been having a bad day. I shouldn't comment on questions when I am frustrated because I am trying to find an answer to a problem of my own.